# Markdown R - Embedded image as logo

Tags: html, r, markdown

I'm trying to put an image as logo, on the right hand side next to the title and want it to work embedded in a single HTML file, but I'm not succeeding (for instance, to share only the HTML file and not both the HTML file and the image).

Here is the code I have:

```
 ---
title: "Title"
header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}
author: "Team"
date: "Date"

output: 
  html_document

---

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $head = $('#header');
     $head.prepend('<img src="Image_I_Want.png\" style=\"float: right;width: 250px;\"/>')


   });
</script>   


<br>

## 1) Some nice title
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The header-includes are all for LaTeX so not surprisingly they won't do anything for HTML.

Comment: @dash2 Sorry, I've updated the example with my last try.

Comment: A round-about fix would be put put your image somewhere (I host my logos on GitHub) and then link to it so you don't need to send the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to **logo.jpg**: 
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a7/e8/fa/a7e8fa149fb23e4cbcfe9e8406b6b911.jpg

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $head = $('#header');
         $head.prepend('<img src=\"logo.jpg\" style=\"float: right;width: 150px;\"/>')
       });
    </script>
    ---
    title: "Title"
    header-includes: \usepackage{graphicx}
    author: "Team"
    date: "Date"

    output: 
      html_document
    ---
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be hard to do using Markdown. Markdown trades simplicity for control. I don't know how it prints out the title where you want your logo to be.

Two possible alternatives:

- Create the HTML using 'knit', then edit it manually.
- Write an RHTML document just using pure HTML.

If you don't know HTML, use a WYSIWYG program (or find a web designer).

The HTML you want is going to be *something* like:

```
<h1>My company title</h1><img style='float:right;' src='myimage.png'>
```